# What should I return from MVC controller in case of an error to make sure DropZone will pick it up

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, dropzone.js

I am using using `DropZone JS` with `MVC`. The `ActionMethod` that saves the images is using a try catch. Now what would I need to return from the `ActionMethod` in case of an error so the front end will pick that up and show the error mark to the user instead of showing everything went successful.

Is it built in with `DropZone` or do I need to bind it to event such as complete? If so, how?

An example of the `DropZone JS` complete event

```
this.on("complete", function (file, response) {
        // If an error has occurred, mark the item as failed
        if (response.code != 200){
        }

        // If it went through successful, show that to the user
        if (response.code == 200){
        }
    });
```

If this would work, in `MVC` I could just return `HttStatusCodeResult` such as 
`return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)` and `return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Ok)`

UPDATED - `ActionMethod`

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveImages()
    {            
        bool isSavedSuccessfully = true;
        string fName = "";
        try
        {
            foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];

                if (HttpPostedFileBaseExtensions.IsImage(file))
                {
                    //Save file content goes here
                    fName = file.FileName;
                    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {

                        var originalDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(string.Format("{0}Images\\", Server.MapPath(@"\")));

                        string pathString = Path.Combine(originalDirectory.ToString(), "Temp");

                        var fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                        bool isExists = Directory.Exists(pathString);

                        if (!isExists)
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);

                        var path = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", pathString, file.FileName);
                        file.SaveAs(path);

                        _testRepository.EditMainPicture("test", pathString, "imageText", 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // TODO Add error logging!!
            isSavedSuccessfully = false;

            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Ok);
    }
```

For some reason if anything else fails within this method, `DropZone` will not pick it up and it will mark as the file has been successfully uploaded. I want it to show an error if anything fails within the `ActionMethod`

Comment: Listen for the [error event](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-error) `dropzone.on("error", function(file, data){...})`. Where's your mvc action code?

Comment: Jasen, add your comment as an answer so I can mark it for you. It does work, but I also had to add the `success` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to listen for the [error event](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-error)

> An error occured. Receives the errorMessage as second parameter and if the error was due to the XMLHttpRequest the xhr object as third.

Example

```
dropzone.on("error", function(file, errorMesage, xhr) { ... });
```